# can Nav2 load multiple planners and controllers; Can the executive choose the appropriate one, or can he run many things in parallel?

Tags: nav2

Is it feasible to load multiple planner plugins like NavFn and Smac planner into nav2 and utilize them in various scenarios? If so, what steps are involved in achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each planner, controller, smoother, etc servers can load and use multiple plugins in their own unique context by sending which you'd like to use in your requests. This can be done using the behavior tree XML by having algorithm selector BT nodes, hardcoded values for algorithms to use in certain tree contexts, or other less trivial solutions to choose the right algorithm to use when you like. You can also call those servers directly from another executive / script and select them as well (i.e. not tied to the BT, but the BT is a good option that's well supported).

I don't believe you can run multiple in parallel, mostly because the way we launch the system is using single threaded executors that can only process one callback at a time. That is not an insurmountable barrier to adjust, but there may be other subtle details since the task servers were not designed to process multiple, parallel threads sharing state. I also don't think its an insurmountable problem, but care would need to be taken to review the servers that you want to run in parallel and make sure any global state that could change between requests is moved and stored into the callback's scope so that it doesn't mess with other parallel requests. It would probably be trivial, but I haven't reviewed those servers with this intention in mind.